# Regex somehow combining AND-operand, NOT-operand, and capture group

Tags: java, regex, match, regex-group

I know you can use a NOT-operand in regex in the following way:

- `[^AB]`: Matches anything but `"A"` or `"B"`
- `A(?!B)`: Matches an `"A"`, not following by a `"B"`
- `(?<!A)B)`: Matches a `"B"` without an `"A"` in front of it

But is it possible to use any of these with an AND and capture-group match? As in:

- non-working pseudo-code `([AB])([AB]&&[^\\1])`: Matches `"AB"` or `"BA"` (but not `"AA"` or `"BB"`)

I'm aware there isn't really an AND-operand in regex, which is another thing that should be fixed simultaneously..

Note that this above is just an example, in my regex `AB` is a bit longer and the capture group isn't right next to it. I just isolated the problem part in this question.

Comment: [`^(?!([AB])\1)[AB]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/RQK0qP/1) ?

Comment: @Gurman Perfect! Feel free to make it an answer, then I'll upvote and accept it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this Regex:

`^(?!([AB])\1)[AB]+$`

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RQK0qP/1)

**Explanation:**

- `^` - asserts the start of the string
- `(?!([AB])\1)` - negative lookahead to validate that `A` is not followed by another `A` or `B` is not followed by another `B`
- `[AB]+` - matches 1+ occurrences of either `A` or `B`
- `$` - asserts the end of the string

Answer (score 1):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/W1Ikek/1)

```
([AB])(?!\1)[AB]
```

In some regex engines, you can *slightly* simplify this by using the following (recursion used) - Java doesn't allow recursion, so this method is not possible in Java.

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/W1Ikek/2)

```
([AB])(?!\1)(?1)
```

---

### Explanation

- `([AB])` Capture a character in the set `AB` into capture group 1
- `(?!\1)` Negative lookahead ensuring what follows doesn't match the text most recently captured by capture group 1
- `[AB]` Match a character in the set `AB`

Comment: Nice, this is actually more readable than Gurman's approach. But since his comment was the fastest and I already stated I would accept that one, I'll accept his. Still +1, and I'll probably use your answer. Thanks!

Comment: @KevinCruijssen no worries, I'm glad I could help. His comment beat my answer in terms of speed :( haha

Comment: Hmm, there is a difference in your two answers I noticed now. Yours matches part of the String, but Gurman's the entire String. When I use `^...$` in your regex, it doesn't work anymore. Interesting. :)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen did you set the `m` modifier for multi-line in regex101. It works with `^...$`. Also, his regex matches 2+ characters, whereas mine matches exactly 2

Comment: @KevinCruijssen is this all part of a larger regex?